# Cannot install Protractor for Angular

Tags: angular, protractor, functional-testing

In order to install Protractor, I need selenium webdriver, so I do:

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
[11:36:11] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[11:36:11] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[11:36:11] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 140.82.118.6:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

so I can't install selenium webdriver. Any suggestions on how to resolve this, since I need functional tests running on my angular web site?

I did what some people sugggested, so now I have this error:

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.1.6
[15:10:59] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
[15:10:59] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[15:10:59] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[15:10:59] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.205.112:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\despovl.ISIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 1):

To install protractor run the below commands in your `cmd` as administrator.

To install protractor run `npm i protractor -g`

To install webdriver run `npm i webdriver-manager -g`

Now to update the webdriver run `webdriver-manager update`

If you get any error in webdriver update run `webdriver-manager clean` then run again the install and update commands.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Ah ok, the error in CMD prompt is actually different. It has to do with my proxy. Before, I did it using MINGW64 command prompt for WIndows (it's different thing thatn command prompt).

Comment: I did how you told me and now I have anotgher error, see my original updated question. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is because you are behind some proxy which is not allowing you to download webdriver

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are behind the proxy. Try

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy=216.58.205.112:443
```

Comment: What is the adress for:
216.58.205.112:443
?